# How to create and send JSON from client side

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

I have a web application. On the client side I basically need to get the values of some fields and turn them into JSON and then send them to the server in an AJAX kind of way.(asynchronous)

How would you do that? I also am using jQuery

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to create JSON (also called stringifying) on the client side, you can use the [stringifier](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/blob/master/json2.js) from json.org. More details about its use [here](http://www.json.org/js.html).

You would then use your normal [`jQuery.ajax(...)`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) like so:

```
function sendJSON(dataToStringify) {
   var stringifiedData = JSON.stringify(dataToStringify);

   jQuery.ajax({
      url: 'http://some.url.here',
      data: {stringified: stringifiedData},
      success: function(data) {
         //code to handle successful AJAX post
      },
      error(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
         //code to handle errors
      }
   });
}
```

Comment: Stringifying is something you need even on using some of the jQuery plugins to get it working on IE, e.g. http://plugins.jquery.com/project/cookies

Answer (score 0):

[json2.js](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/blob/master/json2.js) allows you to convert JavaScript objects to JSON representations using the `JSON.stringify()` function.

[$.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax) will allow you to then pass your string as a query parameter to your server side.

Quick example to tie them both together:

```
$.ajax({
  url: '/someurl',
  data: { json: JSON.stringify(myData) }
});
```